# Laravel previous and next records, return object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get the previous record from a database so I can link to it.

The `$previous_comic` in this function just returns the `published_at` field and I can't do anything with that.

```
public function index()
{
    $newest_comic = Comic::orderBy('published_at', 'DESC')->first();

    $previous_comic = Comic::where('published_at', '<', $newest_comic->published_at)->max('published_at');

    return View::make('comics.index')->with('newest_comic', $newest_comic)->with('previous_comic', $previous_comic);
}
```

I need the object so I can use `{{ $previous_comic->slug }}`

Right now it just returns

> "Trying to get property of non-object."

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comics = Comic::orderBy('published_at', 'DESC')->take(2)->get();

$newest_comic = $comics[0];

$previous_comic = $comics[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 possible scenarios. Maybe one of them will help you:

1) Is your query returning an array of objects, in which case do you need to loop through them to access the property?

2) Have you definitely created the 'slug' fields in your database?

3)Is $previous_comic definitely an object and not an array? IE should you be using $previous_comic['slug']

I'm familiar with Laravel but not massively experienced and I suspect no. 3 is not the cause of your problem.

Hopefully this helps. Feel free to give any extra details if you have them.

Lew.

Answer (score 0):

You should also think about the case when the current record is the first one

```
    $comic = Comic::findOrFail($id);
    $comics = Comic::orderBy('id')->get();

    $current = $orgs->search($org);

    $prev = ($current == 0) ? $comics->count() - 1 : $current - 1;
    $prevComic = $orgs->get($prev);
```